# Why can't i create object attribute inside of an object?

Tags: python, object, decorator

Why i have to type this

```
def call_once(f):
   def wrapper(*args):
       if wrapper.flag == False:
           wrapper.flag = True
           return f(*args)
   wrapper.flag=False
   return wrapper
```

instead of just this

```
def call_once(f):
   def wrapper(*args):
       if wrapper.flag == False:
           wrapper.flag = True
           return f(*args)
       else:
           wrapper.flag=False
   return wrapper
```

isn't it the same?

Comment: Please format your code correctly and what the issue ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer second code isn't running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think through it logically: what happens the first time the `wrapper` is called?

```
if wrapper.flag == False:
```

This cannot work, because `wrapper.flag` has not been given a value yet, so there is no comparison to be made.

The first version works because `wrapper.flag=False` happens before the `wrapper` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your wrapper has the flag attribute first. If it doesn't, it hasn't been called yet.

```
def call_once(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        if not hasattr(wrapper, "flag"):
            wrapper.flag = True
            return f(*args)
    return wrapper


@call_once
def test():
    print("test")


for i in range(0, 5):
    test()
```